# Why does enabling Permalinks make pages not found?

Tags: permalinks, pages, 404-error, wp-redirect

I'm new to Wordpress and am creating a site using v3.9.1 of WordPress.  When I create a new page, I can see it in edit mode, but the URL it is supposedly creating is not found when permalinks is used, but visible when permalinks is disabled.  For example, if I try to create a page called `photos` right below the top level, the editor states the page will be visible at `http://example.com/photos/` when permalinks is `Post name`, but navigating to such page gives the error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /photos/ was not found on this server.

But if I put Permalinks back to `Default` then it becomes visible at `http://example.com/?page_id=4`.

Comment: Go to your Admin Backend, General Settings. What are the values for WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)?

Comment: ok and what is your actual domain name?

Comment: Ok, you need to login to your Host Control Panel, and Delete the Database attached to your install then empty out your root directory, then reinstall WordPress as I am getting the ApacheHaus landing page... nothing related to WordPress

Comment: it works now, but never redirect the www to the domainname as the www. is default behavior

Comment: Should the site and wordpress URLs include the `www`?

Comment: no for wordpress to be `www.example.com` Wordpress must be installed in the root directory of your hosting server.  Login via FTP and look at the / directory...

Comment: See my Answer Below... Has Screenshots

Comment: @ECarterYoung WordPress *does not* have to be installed in root for the site to appear in root of domain, that's why there are separate WordPress address and Site address settings. See [Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) in Codex.

Comment: @Milo I agree there, but I think the OP's original intent was to install in the root.  If so, by redoing the install properly in the root, he can avoid needing to use `.htaccess`

Comment: @WilliamKF - 1. verify that your server has mod_rewrite 2. make sure WordPress can create an .htaccess file 3. make sure your server is set up to parse .htaccess files. You may need to ask your web host these questions. See [Using Pretty Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) in Codex.

Comment: @Milo I've enabled mod_rewrite in Apache (it was off) and added AllowOverride FileInfo which revealed that .htaccess had some errors with Options and Order being used by iThemes Security Tweaks.  Once I dropped those, permalinks now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Site I maintain hosted on GoDaddy.  All HTML seen by the outside world is stored in the `/public_html` directory.  Therefore `/public_html` is considered the root directory of my server.

[image: FileZilla Photo]

This site runs on WordPress 3.9.1.  All that was done, was that GoDady's custom installer package unzipped the WordPress download zip to the `/public_html` directory.  Doing this Manually is easily accomplished by unzipping the WordPress download to a Folder and then uploading the **contents of that Folder(but not the folder)** to your web root.  I suspect you unzipped and then uploaded the containing folder, which would lead to `www.example.com/wordpress` if wordpress was the folder you uploaded.

To fix this, work backwards...

Comment: I'm missing how this helps to resolve my issue.

Comment: By redoing your WordPress install in the manner I describe, you will avoid having to use the `.htaccess file`  If redoing the install is not Possible, see @Milo s comment above.

Comment: Complete reinstall twice now, and same issue each time, new pages do not show up, not found when visiting them. Could iThemes plugin be the cause?

Comment: Looks like enabling permalinks is causing this.

Comment: Check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29)